# How to change specific value in a row, using dictionary and conditions?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements

I would like to change value in one specific row based on value from other columns in the same row. I tried with method `.withColumn()` but it doesn't work as I wanted. What I want to get - set flag `1` when the object has date in dataframe just like in the given dictionary:

```py
objects_ = {'x': [datetime.date(2010, 1, 1), datetime.date(2012, 1, 9), datetime.date(2012, 11, 1)], 'y': [datetime.date(2010, 5, 23), datetime.date(2002, 4, 3)]}
```

| date | flag | obj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | 0 | x |
| 2010-02-03 | 0 | x |
| 2010-02-04 | 0 | x |
| 2010-05-23 | 0 | y |
| 2010-10-13 | 0 | y |

to

| date | flag | obj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | 1 | x |
| 2010-02-03 | 0 | x |
| 2010-02-04 | 0 | x |
| 2010-05-23 | 1 | y |
| 2010-10-13 | 0 | y |

Dates are datetime.date type and dataframe is pyspark's.

Flag for date `2010-05-23` would be `1` only for object `y`  (not for `x` too) as its listed for `y` key in dictionary.

I've made something like this, but I failed. Perhaps, there is some method to avoid the loops?

```py
for x in x_list:
    for y in x_dict[x]:
        df = df.withColumn("flag", when(df["date"] == y, 1).otherwise(df["flag"]))
```

Comment: what is the logic / condition being applied to update the values?

Comment: flag for specifc ```date``` x ```obj``` combination should be ```1```, when such a combination exists in given dictionary .

Comment: how does this dict look like?

Comment: Dictionary looks like in ```objects_``` in my post. Just above the first table.

Comment: `x` has 3 elements and `y` has 2. how do you treat them in your conditions? e.g. what happens in case of the 3rd element in `x`?

Comment: When date of x from dictionary has no representant in the Dataframe - nothing happens. When date of x from dictionary has the representant in the Dataframe - it changes the flag to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create case whens for each of the keys and then pass them to a `coalesce`.

here's the approach

```py
mapper = [func.when((func.col('obj') == k) & func.col('date').isin(v), 1) for k, v in objects_.items()]
# [Column<'CASE WHEN ((obj = x) AND (date IN (DATE '2010-01-01', DATE '2012-01-09', DATE '2012-11-01'))) THEN 1 ELSE obj END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN ((obj = y) AND (date IN (DATE '2010-05-23', DATE '2002-04-03'))) THEN 1 ELSE obj END'>]

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('flag_new', func.coalesce(*mapper, 'flag')). \
    show()

# +----------+----+---+--------+
# |      date|flag|obj|flag_new|
# +----------+----+---+--------+
# |2010-01-01|   0|  x|       1|
# |2010-02-03|   0|  x|       0|
# |2010-02-04|   0|  x|       0|
# |2010-05-23|   0|  y|       1|
# |2010-10-13|   0|  y|       0|
# +----------+----+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This is the solution for a Pandas dataframe.  Missed that OP was using pyspark.

I don't know if this is the proper way to do this, but in cases with relatively few matching conditions, this works well.  I don't think the dictionary is providing much value as you are using it as `key1:[keyA,keyB]` rather than `key1A:value, key1B:value`.  If you only have a single value to match to many keys, it's much easier to use `.isin()`, reduce your matching dictionary to a list with single entries and match to a new column with your 2 keys also merged into a single entry.

```
match_list = [str(v)+str(key) for key, value in objects_.items() for v in value]
DB = [Your dataframe]
DB["Merge"] = DB["Date"].astype(str)+DB["obj"]
DB.loc[DB["Merge"].isin(match_list)==True,"flag"] = 1
DB.drop(columns=["Merge"],inplace=True)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its pandas handling right? I'm looking for something that works on pyspark's DataFrame.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, this is the solution in pandas.  I'll clarify my original answer.